# make only points within UIBezierPath button selectable

Tags: swift, layer, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

My swift code features a custom shape button made from a UIBezierPath. The code should only call the func press if it the user toches the red part if the user touches the green part the func press should not be called. Right now if you touch the green part the func is still called.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let customButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100.0, y: 100.0, width: 200.0, height: 140.0))
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        customButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        
        let aPath = UIBezierPath()
        
        aPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 0))
        
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200.0, y: 40.0))
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 160, y: 140))
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 40.0, y: 140))
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 40.0))
        
        aPath.close()
        
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.path = aPath.cgPath
        
        customButton.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        
        self.view.addSubview(customButton)
        customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(press), for: .touchDown)
        
    }
    
    @objc func press(){
        print("hit")
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to the problem is to subclass `UIButton` into a `FunkyButton`. That button contains the path information.  FunkyButton overrides the `hitTest(_:event:)` method, and checks if the point is contained in the path.
Give this a whirl:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let customButton = FunkyButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100.0, y: 100.0, width: 200.0, height: 140.0))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        customButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        self.view.addSubview(customButton)
        customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(press), for: .touchDown)        
    }
    
    @objc func press(){
        print("hit")
    }

}

class FunkyButton: UIButton {
    let aPath = UIBezierPath()

    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        aPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 0))

        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200.0, y: 40.0))
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 160, y: 140))
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 40.0, y: 140))
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 40.0))

        aPath.close()
        let shapedLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapedLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapedLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapedLayer.path = aPath.cgPath

        layer.addSublayer(shapedLayer)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if self.isHidden == true || self.alpha < 0.1 || self.isUserInteractionEnabled == false {
            return nil
        }
        if aPath.contains(point) {
            return self
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first add your constraint for your custom buttom so community trying to solve problem recognize your problem easily. For example;

```
   customButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                customButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),
                customButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
                customButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
                customButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor)
            ])
```

Your problem is in your code, you are adding padding to your layer over of your  layer already exists in your button itself. So can't recognize your event responder and your function naturally doesn't work.

```
yourGreenPartWhichYouClickable.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
yourRedPartWhichYouClickable.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: I added your constraints I dont know what you mean by yourGreenPart and yourRedPart at the end of your answer because they are the same thing.